# What are the requirements for font identification questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic-definition, font-identification

I have a font that I would like help identifying. How should I construct my question to fit within this site's format?

Answer (score 28):

In order to promote high-quality font-identification questions, we ask that you follow a specific format. If your question has been placed on hold, please edit it to meet the following criteria:

#### ✔ DO: Detail what you’ve attempted already to try and identify your font

There are a few resources out there that can automatically identify your font. The [tag wiki](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) lists the popular tools available. We recommend trying the services listed below before posting a question on our site.

**See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/97415/8708) for tips on getting the most out of these services.**

- [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
- [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)
- [Serif Font Identification Guide](http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php)
- [What Font is](http://whatfontis.com/)
- [Fontspring Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator)
- [Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5+ Font Match](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/fonts.html#match_fonts)
- [FindMyFont](http://www.findmyfont.com)

If the font is on a live webpage, try to identify it using the methods described here:

- [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366)

If none of those give you successful results, let us know which ones you have tried, **and the results**, so that we’re not re-tracing steps you may have already taken.

#### ✔ DO: Tell us where it is from

Sometimes the origin of the font can help provide clues to identify it. As much relevant information as possible will go a long way. Include a link if it’s from a digital source, such as a web font or PDF.

#### ✔ DO: Use a descriptive title

So that we don’t have hundreds of questions titled “What font is this?”, we ask that you be as descriptive as possible in your title. Here are some examples of good titles:

- > What font is used for ACME Inc.’s logo?
- > What font is the body text of this real estate brochure?
- > What font does Example.com use for their navigation menu?

This helps keep the question useful to others and improves searchability. For help describing your font, please see [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29280/).

#### ✔ DO: Add an image featuring the font

We’re not psychic, we need to see the font! You can use the built-in image uploader to include a screenshot of the font. The more glyphs you can provide, the more likely it is to be found.

#### ✘ DO NOT: Ask about multiple fonts in a question

Stack Exchange aims to answer objectively answerable questions. If you’re asking about two fonts in one question, it opens up the potential for multiple correct answers. Keep it to one font per question so that your post fits the Stack Exchange format.
If there are multiple fonts in your image, please identify which font you want identified.

#### Other ways to improve your post

- Check it yourself against common fonts on your computer. We’re real, human designers, giving our time freely. Please don’t ask us to identify Arial.
- Consider if it could be hand-drawn lettering, not a font. Look for characters that appear multiple times – if they vary beyond joins to adjacent letters, it’s probably not a font.
- You should also avoid hot-linking to images on external sites. We cannot dependably rely on the longevity of external hosts, so please use the built-in image uploader.
- You can help with our site’s organization by properly tagging it. Start off by tagging it as [font-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) and narrow it down by using  applicable descriptors such as [serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serif), [sans-serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sans-serif), [blackletter](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackletter), [display](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display), [cursive](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursive), [slab-serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slab-serif). Please do not include superfluous tags such as [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) or [fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts).

### Examples of well-formed font-identification questions

- [(Font identification) Univers-like sans-serif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50459/font-identification-universe-like-sans-serif)
- [Whats the name of the font used in this Mickey Mouse birthday banner?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/35699/)
- [What font family is this Art Nouveau / Jugendstill letter “A” from?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29345/)
- [Which font is used in this Warranty Rewards logo?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45516/8708)

Comment: Two questions: (1) Can new users already upload images? In the old FAQ there was a remark that they should link it and flag the post for the image to be converted. 2) What about the additional tags? [Here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/do-we-want-tag-alerts-for-font-identification-and-critique-questions-and-how-sho?rq=1#comment4797_2359), Matt opted against them.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft 1) Yes, see [here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/673/8708). 2) I am definitely **for** using using as many appropriate tags as possible. The search engine is powerful enough to allow you to filter out font id questions, [like so](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts+serif+-font-identification). Reason being: I may see a font that I recognize as having been posted before. The easier it is to search for, the better.