# Ensure that guidelines for critique and font-identification questions (and similar) are highly visible to new users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, critique, new-users

The more often important guidelines are mentioned and linked, the more likely a new user is to read them before posting a question, which in turn makes it much more likely that the user actually follows the guidelines and thus asks a better question and also reduces frustration, quarrel, etc.

However, until recently the guidelines for font-identification questions and critique questions were neither mentioned in their respective tag wikis nor in the [help center’s on-topic section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I changed the tag wiki on font-identification questions (but not the excerpt) a few days ago; everything else hasn’t changed as of now.

**How can we expect new users to follow our guidelines for those questions, if they can only find them by explicitly searching for them on Meta?**

I thus propose that we:

- Have the tag wikis and their excerpts mention the guidelines.
- Mention the respective question types on the [help center’s on-topic section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and prominently refer to the respective FAQs, e.g., as follows:

  > [This includes questions about:]
  >
  > - The identification of fonts, if certain conditions are met (see [our guidelines for font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/19174)).
  > - Critique about special aspects of a design work (see [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681/19174)).
- Have [these kinds of pop-ups](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/2127008) implemented here. (To see this in action, begin [writing a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the SQL tag.)

The same holds for other types of questions with similar guidelines (if we have any) as well as for other appropriate places that new users might visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great suggestions. I updated the help center as requested and included a blurb within the [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag wiki

The pop-up is out of moderator reach though. I would suggest making a separate feature-request for that so the SE devs can see it.

Comment: That popup's experimental so far, but I'm looking into whether there are plans to expand it.

Comment: Cool, thanks abby!

Comment: Looks like we can look into adding these little tag alerts. You guys should take a stab at the wording in a separate feature-request and see what the rest of the community thinks about the plan.

Comment: @abbyhairboat: That sounds good; thank you. [Here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2353/19174) we go.