# Where's that Font-ID tag alert?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

We've got shiny new font ID guidelines. But there's nothing telling people what the guidelines are until after they've asked the question and someone's closed it - and so every new font ID question is not following the guidelines.

What's happening with that [tag alert](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/do-we-want-tag-alerts-for-font-identification-and-critique-questions-and-how-sho)? Telling people the rules clearly and concisely before they post is a pretty important ingredient to having them follow the rules.

I think users [aren't even notified when their questions are closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186742/why-arent-users-notified-when-their-questions-are-closed). Right now:

- We have a system where users are falling foul of a rule they're unaware of
- We're expecting people to spontaneously check back on their question despite receiving no notifications that anything has happened
- Then we're relying on them noticing a low-contrast technical-looking grey banner they had no reason to expect.

[Here's a guy who seems to have no idea he's broken a secret rule](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46056/can-anyone-tell-me-what-this-font-is-or-which-is-similar-to-this).

---

Edit: no news?

Answer (score 1):

Before we can activate this, we need to put together text that will fit in the alert. I asked for feedback on [what was proposed](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2353/8708), it's currently too long. They should be succinct and concise.

[Here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1084) is an example from Anime.SE:

> [image: tag warning example]

and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/1832306) is the example from SO:

> [image: tag warning example]

I think the formatting of the SQL warning will suit us better. It could include a link to the relevant meta post and have an itemized list of the criteria we're looking for. I'll make suggestions in [that thread](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2356/8708).

---

**Update: This has now been implemented!**

Comment: Makes sense. That other thread is getting unweildy, so how about using comments here (since if it's too long for a comment, it's almost certainly too long?). Here's a suggestion:

Comment: Font identifcation questions must follow **[our guidelines]**. Include an image and the results you got from **[automatic font-ID services]**. One font per question, and describe the font or where you found it in the title.

Comment: @user568458 I like the itemized style of the SQL tag, I think it helps users "check off" if they meet all the requirements. I shortened Scott's suggestion and included one for font-id as well. What do you think? http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2356/8708

Comment: Good, but still a bit long, and doesn't mention automatic stuff (the most important bit) directly. Not sure where the best place to post alternatives is, so [I've editted one in on my answer to that other thread](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2359/3327).