# A list of 'snippets' for commenting

Tags: discussion, faq, comments

Several active users are making a terrific effort in welcoming new people, asking for clarification and pointing out issues in question-asking. I've seen a lot of these **snippets in the comment section**, with some degree of variation, and I think we should create a collection of them that regulars can easily access.

A single answer containing all the snippets should do, I'll leave some of mine. **PLEASE edit to add your own snippets or edit the existing ones.**

Answer (score 14):

Note I: The `[user]` bit of the following should be replaced manually with the user's name. It doesn't add it automatically! Alternatively, you can use [the userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/373250-graphicdesign-stackexchange-comment-snippet-adds-username) to convert `[user]` to the OP's name automatically if you'd like.

Note II: You can find the [**comments shortcode options**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) here.

## Questions

#### Welcoming a New User

> Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in the [Graphic Design Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

```
Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!
```

#### Font Identification

> Hi [user]! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font-identification questions. Please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

```
Hi [user]! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font-identification questions, Please take a look and edit your question to include that information.
```

#### General Computer Questions

> Welcome [user]! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, your question seems to be about general computer issues and is not specific to graphic-design software. We therefore do not have the expertise to answer your question. However, it **may** be suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

```
Welcome [user]! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, your question seems to be about general computer issues and is not specific to graphic-design software. We therefore do not have the expertise to answer your question. However, it **may** be suited for [su].
```

#### Tutorial of Everything (new user)

> Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. What you are trying to achieve is the product of several independent techniques. Please [edit] your question to reduce it to a single aspect that you are struggling with. If you are struggling with many aspects, you can ask separate questions about them (I recommend to start with one question though, so you can benefit from your experience for the others). Also please read [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3592).

```
Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. What you are trying to achieve is the product of several independent techniques. Please [edit] your question to reduce it to a single aspect that you are struggling with. If you are struggling with many aspects, you can ask separate questions about them (I recommend to start with one question though, so you can benefit from your experience for the others). Also please read [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3592).
```

#### Critique

> Hi [user], thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

```
Hi [user], thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!
```

#### Low-Effort Question (new user)

> Hi [user]; thanks for your question. Could please [edit] your question and tell us what you tried that didn’t work? This way we can better understand your problem and know where to start explaining. Please also read [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3592). If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

```
Hi [user]; thanks for your question. Could please [edit] your question and tell us what you tried that didn’t work? This way we can better understand your problem and know where to start explaining. Please also read [this FAQ](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3592). If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!
```

#### Possible Duplicate (new user)

> Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. It seems your questions already has been answered [here]. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in the [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

```
Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. It seems your questions already has been answered [here]. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!
```

#### Brainstorming, Idea Gathering, Free Work (new user)

> Hi [user], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I’m sorry to tell you that brainstorming, idea gathering and requests for free work are off-topic on this site. Therefore, your question might be closed soon. If you want to know more about the site, what questions to ask and how, please have a look at the [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

```
Hi [user], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I’m sorry to tell you that brainstorming, idea gathering and requests for free work are off-topic on this site. Therefore, your question might be closed soon. If you want to know more about the site, what questions to ask and how, please have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!
```

#### “Why was my question downvoted or closed?”

> [Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

```
[Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)
```

## Answers

#### Welcoming a New User

> Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in the [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

```
Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!
```

**Not an Answer**

> Hi [user]! Welcome to Graphic Design SE. We follow a strict question-and-answer format (as opposed to a forum), so I’m afraid your answer might get some downvotes because it doesn’t really answer the question. You can visit our [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to read more about how the site works. Don’t get discouraged, though! We have a lot of unanswered questions that would greatly benefit from some input!

```
Hi [user]! Welcome to Graphic Design SE. We follow a strict question-and-answer format (as opposed to a forum), so I’m afraid your answer might get some downvotes because it doesn’t really answer the question. You can visit our [help] to read more about how the site works. Don’t get discouraged, though! We have a lot of unanswered questions that would greatly benefit from some input!
```

#### Link-Only Answer

> Hi [user], could you please explain a bit more what we’ll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

```
Hi [user], could you please explain a bit more what we’ll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!
```

#### Duplicate of Existing Answer

> Hello [user], thanks for your help! Unfortunately, everything you’re telling us has already been covered by another user’s answer. As we are a question-and-answer site, and not a regular forum; we frown on duplicating answers that have already been given. Sorry to be finicky, but I've flagged your post for removal because of this.

```
Hello [user], thanks for your help! Unfortunately, everything you’re telling us has already been covered by another user’s answer. As we are a question-and-answer site, and not a regular forum; we frown on duplicating answers that have already been given. Sorry to be finicky, but I've flagged your post for removal because of this.
```

## Other

#### Legal Disclaimer (IANAL)

> Nothing in this answer shall be considered legal advice and no attorney-client relationship has been established.

```
Nothing in this answer shall be considered legal advice and no attorney-client relationship has been established.
```

#### Multiple Accounts

> Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Please go to our [help section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact Stack Exchange to have this issue fixed.

```
Hi [user], welcome to Graphic Design SE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Please go to our [help section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact Stack Exchange to have this issue fixed.
```

Answer (score 7):

Some may not know this but we have an auto-comment system over at Stack Apps named [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

To use it, install the plugin, then:

Click the auto link:

> [image]

Most of the snippets already include a welcome message so you should click 'welcome' and remove the auto-welcome message. Go to import/export link:

> [image]

Paste the code at the bottom:

> [image]

Save the code and click the comment to auto add to a comment box:

> [image]

> [image]

### CODE:

```
###[Q]WELCOMING NEW USER
Hi [username], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

###[Q]FONT ID
Hi [username]! We have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

###[Q]TECH SUPPORT OR TOO BASIC
Welcome [username]! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

###[Q]CRITIQUE QUESTION
Hi [username], thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

###[Q]LOW-EFFORT QUESTION
Hi [username], thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

###[Q]PROBABLE DUPLICATE, NEW USER
Hi [username], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. It seems your questions already has been asked [here]. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

###[Q]NEW USER: BRAINSTORMING / IDEA GATHERING / FREE WORK
Hi [username], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I'm sorry to tell you that brainstorming, idea gathering and requests for free work are off-topic on this site. Therefore, your question might be closed soon. If you want to know more about the site, what questions to ask and how, please have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

###[Q]TOO BASIC/HELP FILES ANSWERS THIS
I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this very elementary question is answered fully in the application Help Files. While this question may inquire about commonly used graphic design tools, this has little to do with actual graphic design.

###[Q]WHY WAS MY QUESTION DOWN VOTED OR CLOSED
[Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632)

###[Q]3D QUESTIONS
3D Questions are no longer in scope on our website through community consensus. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics)

###[A]WELCOMING NEW USER
Hi [username], welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

###[A]NOT AN ANSWER
Hi [username]! Welcome to GDSE. We follow a strict Q&A format (as opposed to a forum format), so I'm afraid your answer might get some down-votes because it doesn't really answer the question. You can visit our [help] to read more about how the site works. Don't get discouraged, though! We have a lot of un-answered questions that would greatly benefit from some input!

###[A]LINK-ONLY ANSWER
Hi [username], could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

###LEGAL DISCLAIMER
Nothing in this answer shall be considered legal advice and no attorney-client relationship has been established.

###MULTIPLE ACCOUNTS
Hi [username], welcome to GDSE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Stack Exchange does not support more than one account per user on a site. In case your accounts interact (upvoting your own posts, for example), they are liable to be deleted. Please go to our [help section](/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have this issue fixed.
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the canned comments available from the Low Quality Posts review queue (useful if you want to use these outside of review)...

#### This is commentary on another post, not an answer

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

```
This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).
```

#### This is a “thank you” comment

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

```
Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.
```

#### This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

```
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).
```

#### This is a different question posted as an answer

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

```
If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.
```

#### This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

```
While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
```

---

And again in format ready to use in [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116)...

```
###[A] This is commentary on another post, not an answer
This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

###[A] This is a “thank you” comment
Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

###[A] This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

###[A] This is a different question posted as an answer
If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

###[A] This is a link-only answer (and not spam)
While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
```