# Why was my question downvoted and/or closed?

Tags: discussion

My question was immediately downvoted and/or closed.  I do not know what I did or why this happened.  How can I get my question opened and the downvote removed?

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, I would like to extend a welcome to the site!  If you're new I would **strongly** encourage reading our [faq](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) and taking the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour). If you are worried or want to know:

### What might the downvote be for?

Common reasons include:

- No effort in your question (I will **always** help someone that shows they care, but simply asking with no effort will only disable you and you will not learn unless you try *first*)
- Unclear what you're asking (when asking think as if you're demoing to someone with no design experience because we are not mind readers)
- Seeking a tutorial (we are not a tutorial site)
- A simple Google search could answer your question
- No one understands what your goal is
- You are lacking an example (pictures can speak a thousand words plus we are designers, we like examples)
- Realize in some cases you asking other users to put forth a great deal of effort to answer something. You should be willing to put *as much effort* into your question as you are asking of others to answer it.

### What was the question closed for?

Common reasons include:

- Not in scope with the stack site
- Is an isolated issue that could **only** be answered if someone is on your computer or has your *specific* file to examine
- Cannot be answered
- Answers are one's opinion and not based on facts
- Is a software issue that should really be asked on a software forum

See [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for more detail.

### How can I improve my question?

If I downvoted your question for any of the above it is because I do not think your question is of quality.  If you make a proper edit with details, examples and a list of what you've tried I will be more prone to remove my downvote and cast an upvote.  Our voting system is an aid to help guide people on what is quality and what is not.  The stack site model is unique and unlike many other sites.  For more information, see [How to ask a good question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

However, throwing a childish temper or being rude in the comments will get you a warning and if it continues or progresses it could exceed to a suspension.  Instead, remember this is a **professional** site and people should create questions with the mentality of being an employee in a company and having to ask a manger.

Have a great day and enjoy the site!  If you landed on this page please feel free to browse our meta and get involved in the community.

(check out [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for further details)

---

Link for why your question was downvoted to be used in a comment:

```
[Why your question was downvoted.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)
```

Link for why your question was downvoted and voted to be closed for a comment:

```
[Why your question was downvoted and voted for closure.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)
```

Comment: I was gunna do that... but then thought it may be better in the snippets :)

Comment: that is right, forgot about those, if you haven't updated that document I'll find time later tonight to do it

Comment: Oh I did Matt.. The snippets were updated this morning by me.

Comment: Cool.  I haven't had much time to browse the site, its going to be a very busy month

Comment: [Why your question was downvoted.](//meta.meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)