# Is it good form to comment on why you make a specific edit to a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, comments, down-votes

In a recent question, a comment was made regarding why a question was altered. I thought the idea was productive and a great idea-another learning experience not easily given by a different question. Should this practice be encouraged (added to the Help Centre information)? True, that when making an edit, there is ample space to give reason for changes and edits; but, this must be searched by pressing the "edit" history. Even then, the reasons might not be entirely clear to the questioner (who might have superficial understanding of the subject involved.)

In a related issue, shouldn't all first down votes be defended in comments? (This is only noted as related due to specific reasons for DVs are covered pretty well in the suggested criteria for down votes.) Often, though, the questioner is confused as to why specific DVs were "awarded."

Related (not my question - used it to make my question clearer): What is a good comment to leave for closed critiques? Others?

Comment: You're asking like 3 different questions some of which we've already discussed at length. Regarding the bulk of your issue could you link the question you're thinking about?

Comment: Please edit your question to limit it to just 1 question and try to look for an answer here in meta as well. To answer the (current) third question, see [this list of comment snippets](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473/23061)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanx, I'm reviewing your link and "Related" questions listed in the "sidebar" to the right.

Comment: Regarding "first down votes be defended in comments" (the one Ryan mentioned that it has been discussed at length), Meta Stack Overflow has a dedicated post for this request: [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/2821954)