# Receiving down votes on this question even when a genuine and well explained question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[Can you create a plastic/rubber tube like structure in Photoshop with a specific path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127117/can-you-create-a-plastic-rubber-tube-like-structure-in-photoshop-with-a-specific/127124?noredirect=1#comment189345_127124)

Just because some people can't brainstorm to answer, they keep down voting, just like in this question. This is really bad.

Comment: Not an answer because I can't take a look just now but make sure your question fits these guidelines: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/how-do-i-ask-a-good-question-on-how-to-do-something-with-software?cb=1

Comment: May I urge users not to downvote this question. Though it might be poorly worded, it is a genuine question by a valuable user. There is no need to antagonise them further with additional downvotes.

Comment: do the brainstorming on the chat before asking a more focused question on the main site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First of all a general comment**: people don't downvote just to downvote or to spite a user*. They certainly don't downvote a question because they don't know the answer. In all my years here I have never seen that kind of behaviour. You should not assume this.

---

Now as to ***why* this particular question was downvoted**, I can only guess, since I can't know for sure what the downvoters were thinking.

To be honest, the question feels very much like a *'do my work for me'* type of question, and people tend to dislike that kind of questions. I will give you some reasons why I think this:

- The first comment is 'What have you tried'. A common comment to questions that seem to be too shallow, i.e. request a tutorial more than help with a specific problem. To be fair, you have since added to the question.
- You start with "I need". This sets a tone of neediness. A better approach would be to start with explaining what process you have tried to follow, and what the problem is or why you don't like the result.
- Your question is "Is this possible" but in the question text you state "I know Photoshop has many blending options and effects, so it is possible." This kind of implies that you're assuming it is possible and want someone to tell you *how* to do it, i.e. a tutorial.

On the whole, you give off a vibe of neediness, like a school kid who wants someone else to do their homework for them. I know this is probably not how you wanted to come across, but it is. Try rereading and rewriting your question with a bit more tact, a bit more context and a bit more background.

I invite you to come to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) if you want to talk more about this, because the comments to a question are not a very good place to have a conversation.

---

**Aside**:  I know getting downvoted and not understanding why can be frustrating. Interacting with you on the site and in chat, I can't help but feel there is also a language/culture gap at play. However, I really want to urge you to try and stay polite towards other users, especially those that answer your questions.

---

<sub>*Actually they do sometimes, but that's mostly serial downvotes. The system however is *very* good at picking up this kind of behaviour and will revert the downvotes.</sub>

Comment: I'd add rather than showing any appreciation and progress from the **3 very informative answers**, Vikas has commented about why its not precisely what they want.