# Does the graphic design stack just accept questions on graphic design tools and software?

Tags: discussion

I was curious if questions about graphic design theory are acceptable as well.

EDIT: :( sorry guys I searched for a help section to answer this question but I couldn't find it. In fact I still can't find the ontopic section.

Comment: The top right of your screen, if you're not on App, is a search bar. And directly next to it is the word help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GraphicDesign is specifically deals with how *graphic design*, "the process of visual communication, and problem-solving through the use of type, space and image"<sup>[[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_design)</sup>, is carried out, both in theory and in practice.

Pulled from [our on-topic page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help center:

> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual
>     communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - Digital media
> - The identification of fonts, if certain conditions are met (see our [guidelines for font-identification
>     questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/8708)).
> - Critique about special aspects of a design work (see our [guidelines for critique
>     questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/8708))

Answer (score 10):

Ouch, this is kind of a gut shot.

Yes, we accept questions on design theory. Actually, we prefer them. We've been coping with the problem that the vast majority of our questions *is* tools and software, while we'd like things to be more balanced between the two.

So, please post your questions on design theory, as long as they are objectively answerable, as per the [help center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). We do have some leeway with opinion-based questions and critique (moreso than most other stacks), but not very much.

Answer (score 6):

Most regulars here **want** more theory questions and grow weary of the constant barrage of software support questions.

By all means, if you've got theory questions post them! Just be aware of how you word them so they can gain at least partially objective answers.

Answer (score 3):

PLEEEEEEEEEASE! I pray there are more interesting questions regarding design theory and visual comunication! Please!