# Why not require more keyword injection for font identification questions

Tags: discussion

In my opinion, font identification are quite useless for this site. I know you discussed all this before.

I'm basing this on the fact they can (almost) only be useful with a google image search, and not with the question's keywords. There's almost zero value for the site as they are right now.

1. Because the questions are (almost) all the same and mostly contain
   only a screenshot and a "please help!"; not much descriptive keywords that can be used as search terms
2. Because the titles of the questions are (petty much) all the same
3. Because the answers cannot be very long answers

They would have value if it was "help me find a font similar to XXXX" but in general it's about asking for help to identify a font on a screenshot/image.

So this is a suggestion...

**Why not change the instructions to demand from people posting the questions to actually DESCRIBE the font.** Have a minimum number of words maybe or ask for 3 adjectives. That could even lead to entertaining results.

This could become the main requirement.

It's pretty much useless to ask them "have you check the font id sites?" That's like asking a dog to guard your sandwich. Of course everybody say they have checked the sites first!

---

**Example (yes I know, I'm guilty, [I answered it](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63820/can-someone-please-tell-what-font-is-used)):**

> Title: *Can someone please tell what font is used*
>
> Question: *Could someone please tell me what font is used in the
> following image*
>
> --- screenshot ----

**"Improved" version:**

> Title: *Can someone please tell what font is used* (meh)
>
> Question: *Can someone help me find this thin semi-script font. It
> looks a bit like a handwritten but has a modern and vibrant style to
> it. It's kind of feminine. I want to use it for a bakery website
> because blablabla... etc.*
>
> --- screenshot ----

---

## Edit:

As members, we could add keywords too in the questions. It's way easier to define keywords than trying to enforce rules that are followed 10% of the time. And the vote-to-close isn't always super fast, people will have time to answer anyway  -- coughs --

We can't expect people to use the right tags,  because some people don't even know what's a serif and there's not so many descriptive tags for fonts.

The end goal anyway is to have content that appear in search results (as I said, I personally think the font identifications are a waste of pixels and should be removed... unless they bring more traffic and can be useful somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

As the person that wrote the font requirements I fail to see how this is any different. [What are the requirements for font identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions) --- like you said your guilty. The only way people are going to respect the Font ID requirements is if the regular members equally enforce them.

Beyond downvoting and close voting if the Question is close members can also help the person asking by editing to be more descriptive or add new tags to get it to be useful. If its not something that can be edited to be useful it should probably be getting closed.

The requirements already state: tell us where it came from, provide a screenshot, tell us what you tried, and tag it appropriately.

Comment: The font ID requirements are well done but still a wall of text. Other users focus on "have you tried id sites" because that seems to be the requirement repeated most of the time. The example of good questions don't contain much more text than "it's been a long journey searching and alas I sadly had no luck on XYZ and ABC" ;) That's mainly SEO for font squirrel while adjectives would be more useful. Good questions and tagging are from people knowing the fonts (eg. the Univers question example on the font requirement).

Comment: Having a re-usable link like Darth did for the screenshot isn't a bad idea for all of us (eg. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font).  <----- well, ok I thought the title of the question would appear here like in the answers...and not just a url.. :/