# Live webfont identification

Tags: discussion, font-identification

I've noticed that quite often, font identification requests are live web fonts.
 Since it's very easy to Inspect them and to get the "font-family" css, I was thinking that adding a paragraph to [this Post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) about webfont inspection could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've [updated the font-id requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2366/12) to include this:

> If the font is on a live webpage, try to identify it using the methods described here:
>
> - [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366)

That Q&A includes an explanation of using the browser's inspector as well as a couple of other methods (extensions etc.) so is a good resource I think.

Comment: Minor note: webpages don't have to be "live" in the online sense for that question talks about. It could be an offline file. I feel like using "live" is misleading

Comment: @Zach good point (in that case they'd of course already *have* the font, but if they don't know how to check what the font is I guess that doesn't change anything). I think the important distinction is that it's live text rather than say an image of text... I'll see if I can reword it a bit better later

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather sure it would! Ideally, you'd like to have this tip mentioned in the closing message, but that one is already very cramped (the length of close messages is limited).

Comment: What do you think about including a link to [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366/52050) in the requirements post?