# Help center page links to redirects with HTTP errors

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the help center for Graphics Design, the highly visible page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has some broken links.  It says

> For some kinds of questions that are a weird fit for our Q&A model, we have rules to keep them fitting and answerable:
>
> - [font identification](https://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366);
> - [critique](https://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682);

The two links point to redirects that has an invalid https certificate.  The SE overlords [have declared that this is an error they will not fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299087/222298), so those URLs will forever give errors (thanks to [SFTP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/315433/sftp) for pointing this out).

Luckily per-site **diamond moderators** have the power to change the text on that help center page.  So I ask the moderators to change the links to the current ones:

> For some kinds of questions that are a weird fit for our Q&A model, we have rules to keep them fitting and answerable:
>
> - [font identification](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366);
> - [critique](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682);

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now. Thanks for spotting.